# ".MainActivity" in <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> is not a concrete class

Tags: android

When inspecting my code, I get an error in the AndroindManifest.xml saying that

> ".MainActivity" in <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> is not a concrete class.

The App is, therefore, crashing in the Emulator of Android Studio.

Here is the Java Code of the Application:

```
package de.thi.donotpressthebutton;

import android.media.MediaPlayer; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.niggaz_audio );
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                audio.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And here is the XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.thi.donotpressthebutton">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> **//error**
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add MainActivity code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is not a concrete class AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597304/is-not-a-concrete-class-androidmanifest)

Comment: Check duplicate declaration and also check that class define is public or not

Comment: add manifest  and MaiActivity code

Comment: maybe you created your mainactivity in a folder

Answer (score 0):

If your `mainactivity.java` is not in the package root directory, you should add the folder name. For example, `mainactivity.java` in the `com.balbala.holleworld/View/`folder should be `<activity android:name=".view.MainActivity">` instead of `<activity android:name=".view.MainActivity">`. Hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The other Reason For this Type Of Error Might Be That You Have Accidentally Used "Abstract"
Keyword Before the Activity Name That Might Have Caused The Problem In The Project